# How to open csv file do split on every row save it and close it

Tags: python-3.x, csv, split

I have a simple problem but cannot solve it properly. I would like to open .csv file, split values on every row by "," save the operation and then close the file. So then when I will open that .csv file next time the values will be separated into rows and columns (like one value - one cell in the excel, not like one cell with many values separated by comma).
Thank you very much in advance.

Have many versions of code but no one works. I would like to not use pandas for this but csv mode. It should looks like this:

```
import csv

with open('AH.csv', "w") as csvfile:
    for row in csvfile:
        csvfile.split(",")

csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to split the row by lines "\n" on linux, "\r\n" on windows.
Then you go through each row and split them by columns.

It looks like you are only open the file to write, not to read, but you are reading it.

Since i am not often working on Python, i added a JavaScript example below.
Logic stays the same.

```js
let filecontent = "Name,Age\nJulia,23\nJohn,25\nTom,33";

let splitted_rows = filecontent.split('\n');

let table = [];

for(let i = 0; i < splitted_rows.length; ++i) {
 let splitted_columns = splitted_rows[i].split(",");
 table.push(splitted_columns);
}

console.log(table);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(table);
```

```html
<div id="output">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :-)